# NSDateFormatter string format for showing milliseconds

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter

I need to retrieve the current date with this format:

> yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss-XXX

But which are the letters to use for the milliseconds?

Comment: Read up on this document: [Date Format Patterns](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As is documented by [Unicode](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns), `S` means fractional second:

> Fractional Second - rounds to the count of letters. (example is for 12.34567)

Use as many `S` as needed for the given precision.

Answer (score 4):

The letters for miliseconds are SS, so you should do:

> yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss-SSS